# Fetch friends count using Odnoklassniki API in Ruby

Tags: ruby, api

looking for working solution to **Fetch friends count using Odnoklassniki API  in Ruby**
tried to use **lemur** and **school_friend** gems without success

```
require 'school_friend'
SchoolFriend.application_id = '193320768'
SchoolFriend.application_key = 'CBALsdsASDBA'
SchoolFriend.secret_key = 'A3AA9342CR47DA4BC315'
SchoolFriend.api_server = 'http://api.odnoklassniki.ru'
puts SchoolFriend.users.is_app_user(:uid => '571931088692')

{"error_code"=>100, "error_data"=>nil, "error_msg"=>"PARAM : Missed required parameter: access_token"}
```

even i specify access_token as mentioned in docs like that:

```
session = SchoolFriend.session(:access_token => 'token_from_oauth2_client')
session.friends.get
{"error_code"=>100, "error_data"=>nil, "error_msg"=>"PARAM : Missed required parameter: access_token"}
```

i still get same error

Comment: did you change the debug level? `SchoolFriend.logger.level = Logger::DEBUG`

Comment: [19] pry(main)> puts session.friends.get
D, [2013-09-30T21:39:35.247478 #1466] DEBUG -- : API Request: http://api.odnoklassniki.ru/api/friends/get?application_key=CBAdsdsdABABABA&sig=c7aef83esdsdsdsds05a3ffb010
{"error_code"=>100, "error_data"=>nil, "error_msg"=>"PARAM : Missed required parameter: access_token"}

Answer (score 0):

Becouse odnoklassniki api requires access token

your request to this api should be like

```
http://api.odnoklassniki.ru/fb.do?method=friends.get&application_key=[APPLICATION_KEY]&sig=[SIG]&access_token=[ACCESS_TOKEN]
```

I'm use lemur and for me it works fine
i'm initialize it like

```
odnoklassniki = Lemur::API.new(APP_SECRET, Public_key, Access_token, APP_ID)
```

where APP_SECRET, Public_key and APP_ID you have after registration your app
Access_token you have after use sign in to odnoklassniki via omniauth
and then i can call api method like

```
odnoklassniki.get(method: 'friends.get')
```

this returns something like that

```
["55726542234", "32131394541", "532139395874", "94691213891"]
```

Comment: i get this: Lemur::ApiError: {"error_code"=>10, "error_data"=>"valuable_access", "error_msg"=>"PERMISSION_DENIED : User must grant an access to permission 'VALUABLE_ACCESS'"}

Comment: Becouse you don't have VALUABLE_ACCESS to odnoklassniki, so you could not use any api methods without 'users.getCurrentUser'
To have VALUABLE ACCESS you should go to this [link](http://www.odnoklassniki.ru/devaccess), or write to odnoklassniki developers via email  
To learn more about odnoklassniki api go to [link below](http://apiok.ru/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=50888859)

Comment: Права разработчика выданы. Перейдете по ссылке, чтобы управлять приложениями.

Comment: хорошо, тогда тебе нужно написать email на oauth@odnoklassniki.ru, с просьбой предоставить тебе valuable_access, где указать Application ID, название твоего приложения на одноклассниках, твой uid, login и email на одноклассниках, a также причину по которой тебе нужен valuable_access, затем останется только ждать ответа от их админестрации